# No Java virtual machine could be found from your path

Tags: software-installation, java, environment-variables, jdk, openjdk

I am trying to install a program that is using Java, but it gets stuck when searching for the JVM.

Running `java -version` I get openjdk version `1.8.0_151`

My current `$PATH` parameter contains `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin`
and my `$JAVA_HOME`: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/`

However, when I run the installer I get

```
No Java virtual machine could be found from your PATH environment variable
```

I've updated both `/etc/environment` and `/etc/profile`

What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you running the installer with `sudo`? In that case, try `sudo env PATH="$PATH" ...`

Comment: I'll try that, but I get the exact same error running both with and without sudo

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas; hopefully someone else can help.

Comment: Some versions of Eclipse Mars, to give one example, require Oracle Java to be installed, and if you already have openjdk-8-jdk from the Ubuntu repos installed, Eclipse will not automatically detect that Java is installed because it looks for Java in the location where the Oracle Java executable is normally installed.

Comment: Could you say what is the program that you tried to install? Is it maybe that the program uses some parameters from own configuration files?